# SQL : More records in update than in select

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table containing unwanted characters ('‘' and '’') in the TEMPLATE column

When I execute this query 3 records are returned.

```
SELECT *
FROM T_MO_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_BASE 
WHERE INSTR(TEMPLATE,'‘') > 0 OR INSTR(TEMPLATE,'’') > 0 ;
```

I want to update the TEMPLATE column by replacing these unwanted characters.
When running the update script below, 94 records are updated. How is that possible if only 3 records have these unwanted characters?

```
UPDATE T_MO_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_BASE 
SET TEMPLATE = CASE 
                    WHEN INSTR(TEMPLATE,'‘') > 0 THEN REPLACE(TEMPLATE,'‘','')
                    WHEN INSTR(TEMPLATE,'’') > 0 THEN REPLACE(TEMPLATE,'’','')
               END
```

Comment: You don't have a WHERE on your UPDATE and so every row is being updated. And since you don't have an `ELSE` on your case expression, then you are setting all non-matching `TEMPLATE` to null. Consider instead `SET TEMPLATE = CASE WHEN INSTR(TEMPLATE,'‘') > 0 THEN REPLACE(TEMPLATE,'‘','') WHEN INSTR(TEMPLATE,'’') > 0 THEN REPLACE(TEMPLATE,'’','') ELSE TEMPLATE END` which will still update all rows, but won't cause your data to be deleted (although it may be too late for that if you didn't make a backup)

Comment: Correct statement should then be:

UPDATE T_MO_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_BASE 
SET TEMPLATE = CASE 
                    WHEN INSTR(TEMPLATE,'‘') > 0 THEN REPLACE(TEMPLATE,'‘','')
                    WHEN INSTR(TEMPLATE,'’') > 0 THEN REPLACE(TEMPLATE,'’','')
                    ELSE TEMPLATE
               END
WHERE INSTR(TEMPLATE,'‘') > 0 OR INSTR(TEMPLATE,'’') > 0 ;

Comment: Btw, third argument is redundant in this case for `REPLACE()` function. eg. using `REPLACE(template,'‘')` is enough.

Comment: You can also nest `REPLACE`, i.e. first remove the ` from the string then remove ´ from that: `UPDATE t_mo_email_template_base SET template = REPLACE(REPLACE(template, '‘'), '’') WHERE template LIKE '%‘%' OR template LIKE '%’%';`.